# Get youtube views using facebook application

Tags: facebook, youtube-api

Can I show the number of views for YouTube video from my FaceBook application . I need only views via my application not all views from YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a facebook question, but you will be using the YouTube API.

Here is an answer explaining it: [How to get number of video views with YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api)

Comment: Thanks Adam .. but I got this answer before but my question to show only the number of views via my application only so if my youtube video was watched 50 times and it was watched by my facebook application by only 10 times so I need to show only 10 views not all 50 . I hope I showed the problem in clear way

Comment: A youtube video on Facebook is just a flash object. The only thing I could think of was seeing if there is a value on Facebook seeing how many times an object has been viewed or if the Youtube API could filter the source of the views. I found no option for either.