# Youtube api with category

Tags: php, api, youtube

i trying use skrypt  from 6 hours [How to get number of video views with YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api#new-answer)

```
<?php
$video_ID = 'your-video-ID';
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views;
?>
```

why it don't work?

```
$JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'media$group'}->{'media$category'}->{'$t'};
```

the code to decode:

```
"media$category":[{"$t":"Entertainment","label":"Rozrywka","scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"}],
```

I think the problem is at "[" "]", how should look like? Thank you very much

Comment: Do you need any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`media$category` is array format so you can use `{'media$category'}[0]`

Code in file_get_contents

```
$video_ID = 'BM7FWtADD0s';
$url =  "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json";
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$category = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'media$group'}->{'media$category'}[0]->{'$t'};
echo $category;
```

Output : `Entertainment`

Code in curl

```
      $c = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($c, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER =>false
    ));
    $json = curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c);
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($json);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'media$group'}->{'media$category'}[0]->{'$t'});
```

Output : `Entertainment`