# Fetching the views from youtube

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js

**Is it possible to fetch the youtube views for our video using some queries or request?**
How can i enhance my viewership on my video by giving views to my video?

Comment: Answer for your question : _Yes!_

Comment: how can we do that? i want to enhance my viewership on my video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube API V2 is deprecated, so you got to use API V3 [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/](http://V3%20API). For using V3 first of all you need to get your application authenticated by the API and get the API key. Once you have that, if you are using PHP you could do something like this

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={YOUR-VIDEO-LINK-ID}&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

$views = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
echo $views;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible using youtube apis, please refer to the below question :
[How to get number of video views with YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api)

Comment: Thanks. So, with the help of this, can i increase my YT views either fake or organic?

Comment: Although there are tools available online that claim that they can increase YT views, but I don't think that its possible because google has many algorithms that continuously monitor the requests in order to identify and discard malicious requests.

Comment: what about creating a bot changing proxies and visiting links?

Comment: Give it a shot, and if you are successful do inform me.