# Using VBA to scrape Youtube Data: Issue with Pulling View Data, 462 Error

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

I am getting a 462 error (the remote server does not exist or is unavailable):

```
Set QuestionField = html.getElementsByClassName("view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer")
```

I'm pretty sure the view information I'm trying to pull is in a class tag, and I am unsure why getElementsByClassName isn't working to pull this information.

Here is the relevant HTML code from YouTube:

```
<
span class="view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer">952 views
<
/span>
```

Here is the VBA Code:

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub ImportYTData()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://www.youtube.com/watch?    v=0YNJQNpP9Do&list=PL_Lt8vbVLfk_pzt-TWzfk_GNAKp-ePXc1&index=22"
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to the YouTube Video ..."
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.document
MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

Application.StatusBar = ""

Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim QuestionField As IHTMLElement
Dim views As String

Set QuestionField = html.getElementsByClassName("view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer")
RowNumber = 4

views = QuestionField.innerText
views = Replace(views, "views", "")
views = Replace(views, "view", "")
Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Trim(views)

Set html = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you wanna scrape actually from that very page? Are you after all the reviews available attached to every videos?

Comment: _"the remote server does not exist or is unavailable"_ suggests that the problem is in contacting the remote server.

Comment: @Shahin I just want the view count

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you are calling a function `getElements` which is plural.  This function is returning a collection which your are trying to assign to a single element.  In other words, there is a mismatch.

```
Set QuestionField = html.getElementsByClassName("view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer")
```

One solution would be to change your DIM statement to:

```
Dim QuestionField As IHTMLElementCollection
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I am getting a 462 error with Set QuestionField = html.getElementsByClassName("view-count style-scope yt-view-count-renderer")

Comment: The call to `getElements` is returning nothing and your code is assuming something will be returned.  You need to add more code to handle this situation.  Also, remember a collection is being returned so you'll need to either loop through the results, or pull off the first element, before accessing properties.